# show that $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(t)^n dt = 4\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(t)^n dt$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to show that $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(t)^n \mathrm{dt} = 4\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(t)^n \mathrm{dt}$ if $n=2m$ but I don't understand the transition? Should I apply $u$ substitution?

Comment: What is $m$? Is it an integer?

Comment: first do $t \mapsto -t$ then $t \to \pi - t$

Comment: Yes, m is an integer

Comment: A visualisation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/om262csvgn

Comment: $\cos ^2t$ is $\pi$-periodic and so $\int^\pi_0\cos^{2m}t\,dt =\int^{-\pi/2}_{\pi/2}\cos^{2m}t\,dt=...$

Answer (score 0):

First note that the function is an even function, i.e. $f(-x) = f(x)$

There is a property of integration of even functions,
$$\boxed{\int _{-a}^{a} f(x) \ dx = 2 \int_0^a f(x)\ dx }$$

Therefore,
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(t)^{n}\ dt =  2\int_0^\pi \cos(t)^n dt\  {\rm{Where }}\ n = 2m, m \in \mathbb{Z} $$

The period of the function is $\pi$. The area under the curve between the limits $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ is similar.

$$\implies 2\int_0^\pi \cos(t)^n dt = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}  \cos(t)^n dt + 2 \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}  \cos(t)^n dt$$

$$\implies 2\int_0^\pi \cos(t)^n dt = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}  \cos(t)^n dt + 2\int_0^{\pi/2}  \cos(t)^n dt $$

$$\implies 2\int_0^\pi \cos(t)^n dt = 4\int_0^{\pi/2}  \cos(t)^n dt $$

And hence,
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(t)^{n}\ dt = 4\int_0^{\pi/2}  \cos(t)^n dt$$